# Google Sheets- Changing specific rows from another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have two spreadsheet. One of them for updating and another one is for changing data. The problem is everytime i update the first spreadsheet i have to do the changes again.

For example in my first spreadsheet i have more than 500 players with stats and this data updates every single day. On my second spreedsheet i have changes that needs to be done evertime. However these changes doesn't change.

Sheet1

Number / Name / Team / Stats

1      / JJ  / HO / 1-2-3..

500 / XX / AA / 5-6-7...

Sheet 2

Number / Name / Team / ...

1/  JJ/ HO/ 0-0-0-0

So what i need is whenever first sheet upated i want to change specific ones according to sheet 2

Comment: What changes you want to second sheet? Do you want only updated/latest stats for every player?

Comment: @Harun24HR There will be no changes in second sheet. Second sheet has some values but they don't change however the first one updates itself. When it updates i want to change several players stats accoring to second sheet. Because these players are same but has different stats.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. What do you want to change, and on what event do you want them to change? Can you share a copy of your sheets?